# Apache solr indexed data not visible even after commit

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, jetty

I am not able to find the indexed data of the files during search
Below are the steps I am following
OS: Windows 7
Solr version: solr 5.2.1
Steps:

1. cd ..\solr 5.2.1\bin
2. solr start -e techproducts
3. Check if solr is up and running and core is visible. Search for the indexed files. Total 32 files exists and shown in the search result .
4. cd ..\solr-5.2.1\example\exampledocs
5. curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/update/extract?literal.id=33&commit=true" -H "myfile=@example/exampledocs/test.pdf"
6. Result: It shows successfully indexed and committed but the files returned from the search are still 32 files.
7. try with other way of indexing ... java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts/update/extract -Dparams=literal.id=33 -jar post.jar test.pdf It indexed and committed successfully
8. Open solr GUI and do a search now 33 files returned , but can not see any information of the test.pdf file, meta data and data both not visible
9. Restart the solr
10. now we can see the data of the file

Surprisingly instant commit worked for me just a day before with the same configuration, once I did delete all index, from then I am facing this problem not only with this solr instance for other solr instances in the same machine.

Below are the `autocommit` config from `solrconfig.xml`

```xml
<autoCommit>
    <maxTime>${solr.autoCommit.maxTime:15000}</maxTime>
    <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
</autoCommit>

<autoSoftCommit>
    <maxTime>${solr.autoSoftCommit.maxTime:-1}</maxTime>
</autoSoftCommit>
```